# pipe saved file output of gnome-screenshot -a into another command

Tags: gnome

I've been looking through gnome-panel-screenshot's manpage: http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/gnome-panel-screenshot/ and I don't see any way to obtain the captured shot.

What I'd like to do:

1. call gnome-screenshot -a to auto select area-picker
2. draw my area
3. when I let go, it's going to prompt me to name the file and save it
4. I when I name this file, I want it to immediately pipe to (to upload it to my server):

`rsync -avzh -e "ssh" $@ me@remote:/var/www/images`

Does anyone know how I can automate steps 3 and 4?

Comment: `scrot -s` is also something i'm willing to use, i just need to find a way to get the image into that function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with this, would love to learn about better techniques though!

```
function screeny() {
    scrot -s -e 'rsync -avzh -e "ssh" $f me@remote:/var/www/images'
}
```